# Getting an 'Cannot create an instance of an interface'-error with EF Plus IncludeFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, entity-framework-plus

Having an `IList<Guid>`, I wish to locate all matches from the context and then include a number of related tables, where outdated data are not included. 
Because of the size of the data, I try to use EF Plus IncludeFilter, to avoid loading all to memory and perform the filtering there. 
The problem occurs when I call `ToListAsync()` on the query. IncludeFilter (as far as I can see) then throws a `System.MissingMethodException : Cannot create an instance of an interface` exception.

The project is done in .NET Core 2.2, and I using Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore 2.0.7

**Sample project**

This sample recreates the issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MYukHp

**Data structure**

The database structure centers around the Facts table which contains an immutable Guid, identifing each entry. Entries in all other tables link to this guid to bind together to a single entry. The other tables contain a `DateTime ValidTo` to track changes. No entries are ever updated or deleted. Instead, on change a new entry is made with `ValidTo = DateTime.MaxValue`, and the entry being updated has it's `ValidTo` set to `DateTime.Now`.
This ensures that all changes are preserved historically.

Over time, the vast majority of data will be historical, so it's crucial that we can filter this out in the SQL query.

The data structure for the Fact-table is like this:

```cs
public class FactModel
{
    public Guid FactId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public IEnumerable<PersonModel> Persons { get; set; }
    // Repeat for all other tables
}
```

All other tables inherits from a ModelBase, linking them to the Fact table.

```cs
public class ModelBase
{
    public Guid FactId { get; set; }    // Link to the Fact
    public FactModel Fact { get; set; }  // Navigation property
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; } 
    public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }   // ValidTo == DateTime.MaxValue -> active record
}
```

Example tables for Person and Patient

```cs
public class PersonModel : ModelBase
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }    // Key - A new is created on every update
    public string FirstName { get; set; }  // data
    public string LastName { get; set; }   // data
}

public class PatientModel : ModelBase
{
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }  // Key - A new is created on every update
    public Guid ActiveCompanyId { get; set; }  // Data
    public int HealthInsuranceGroup { get; set; } // Data
    public PatientStatusType Status { get; set; } // Data
}
```

Changing the parameter to IQueryable produces a new error: 
`System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type System.Guid' to type 'System.String'`

**Call sequense**

The call sequence is rather complex, but simplified we start by declaring the call parameter `IQueryable<FactModel> facts`. This is filtered by only adding *Patients* from the company the user is logged into. Then the search term is applied. Finally, the parameter is transformed into a list containing only the need guids, before calling `AssignDataToPatientByFactId`.

```cs
// Performing a search for an Address

IQueryable<FactModel> facts = null;
facts = _context.Facts.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.Patients.Any(a => a.ActiveCompanyId == _identificationHandler.Identification.CompanyId));
facts = facts.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.Addresses.Where(z => z.ValidTo == DateTime.MaxValue).Any(q => q.Street.Any() && q.Street.StartsWith(searchDTO.SearchString)));
return await AssignDataToPatient(facts.Select(x => x.FactId).ToList()), cancel);
```

```cs
public async Task<List<FactModel>> AssignDataToPatientByFactId(IList<Guid> factIds, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    return await _context.Facts.Where(x => factIds.Contains(x.FactId))
        .IncludeFilter(x => x.Patients.Where(c => c.ValidTo == DateTime.MaxValue))
        .IncludeFilter(x => x.Persons.Where(c => c.ValidTo == DateTime.MaxValue))
        .IncludeFilter(x => x.Communications.Where(c => c.ValidTo == DateTime.MaxValue))
        .IncludeFilter(x => x.Addresses.Where(c => c.ValidTo == DateTime.MaxValue))
        .ToListAsync(cancel);
}
```

So `AssignDataToPatientByFactId` takes a list of guids, finds all matching in the Facts-table and then adds the entries from the other tables where the `ValidTo` timestamp is Max. So all other entries should not be included.

Separating the code into several statements reveal that IncludeFilter seems to be working, but calling ToListAsync produces the error.

Comment: There's not enough detail here I think, can you show what the `Fact` entity looks like?

Comment: I've updated the question, providing some background information. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Not really, can you show us the actual fact table class?

Comment: Added ``FactModel`` and sample table structure. Would it simplify if I omitted the ``ModelBase`` and just included in ``PersonModel``?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the AssignDataToPatientByFactId ?

Comment: Added example code for the call to AssignDataToPatientByFactId.

Comment: What is the error?!

Comment: I get an ``System.MissingMethodException : Cannot create an instance of an interface`` exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The version v2.0.8 has been released fixing this issue.

The issue was caused because the class `Fact` was using `IEnumerable<T>` properties which were not yet supported by our library.

The Fiddle is now working as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MYukHp

Comment: Would this issue also apply to IReadOnlyCollection<T> with a backing field the EF Core knows about via `navigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field)`? I am receiving the same error in this scenario with 3.2.8